# Youtube IFrame Player API - How to load suggested videos in same iframe

Tags: javascript, youtube-api, youtube-iframe-api

I have implemented a youtube player using javascript IFrame Player API. In this, I can able to play video but after the video finishes it shows the recommended videos list while clicking that it automatically opens a new tab. I need that needs to open in the tab itself. How to achieve that. I referred documentation but could not able get it.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
    <!-- 1. The <iframe> (and video player) will replace this <div> tag. -->
    <div id="player"></div>

    <script>
        // 2. This code loads the IFrame Player API code asynchronously.
        var tag = document.createElement('script');

        tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
        var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
        firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

        // 3. This function creates an <iframe> (and YouTube player)
        //    after the API code downloads.
        var player;

        function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
            player = new YT.Player('player', {
                height: '390',
                width: '640',
                videoId: 'M7lc1UVf-VE',
                playerVars: {
                    'playsinline': 1,
                    'rel': 0
                },
                events: {
                    'onReady': onPlayerReady,
                    'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
                }
            });
        }

        // 4. The API will call this function when the video player is ready.
        function onPlayerReady(event) {
            event.target.playVideo();
        }

        // 5. The API calls this function when the player's state changes.
        //    The function indicates that when playing a video (state=1),
        //    the player should play for six seconds and then stop.
        var done = false;

        function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
            if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING && !done) {
                setTimeout(stopVideo, 6000);
                done = true;
            }
        }

        function stopVideo() {
            player.stopVideo();
        }
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```